# Solve $\sqrt[3]{3-2x} + \sqrt{3x^2+4} = \frac{x}{2} + 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I tried letting $u$ = the cube root and $v$ for the square root and reach some easy system of equations, it did not work for me, I still got $x$ in the system of equations. I tried expressing them all as a function of $x/2 + 2$ or $3-2x$ but it did not seem like a great simplification. Algebraic solutions are preferred.

Comment: $x=2$ is a solution.

Comment: $1.6397$(Using Desmos) is also a real solution other than $2$.So there are total $2$ real solutions of above equation.

Comment: Is this Problem created by you? Solving after removing radicals here is difficult.

Comment: How do you have this problem? Perhaps the closed form expression doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You started off on the right track.

Let $v^2 = 3x^2 +4$ and $u^3 = 3-2x$. Now, we have the relation
$$x = \frac{3-u^3}{2} \quad x^2 = \frac{v^2-4}{3}$$
squaring the first equation, gives us the following relation between $u$ and $v$.
$$\frac{v^2 - 4}{3} = \left( \frac{3-u^3}{2}\right)^2$$
simplifying this gives
$$v^2 = 3\left(\frac{3-u^3}{2}\right)^2 + 4$$
On the other hand, we also have from the main equation
$$u+v = \frac{3-u^3}{4} + 2$$
solving for $v$ and squaring gives
$$v^2 = \left(\frac{11-4u - u^3}{4}\right)^2$$
So, you have two equations now for $v^2$, equate both to get
$$\left(\frac{11-4u - u^3}{4}\right)^2 = 3\left(\frac{3-u^3}{2}\right)^2 + 4$$
This is a sixth degree equation in $u$, but there wont be any odd exponents; so you can let $t = u^2$ to get a cubic equation in $t$ which should be more or less easy to solve given that you have $x=2$ already a solution as suggested in the comments (now use that and follow the right steps through $u$ and $v$ to find the $t$ corresponding to $x=2$). Now, you can use the rational root theorem to reduce to a quadratic and find the roots for $t$ using the quadratic formula. Then backtrack your steps to find all possible $u$ (basically $u = \pm\sqrt{t}$), from which you can get all possible $x$'s (use the first relation in my answer relating $x$ and $u$). From the final list, take the real $x$ values which is the answer you seek.

The last bit is a little long and painful to calculate, but isn't too hard in spirit, which is why I am not filling in all the details. All the best!

Comment: Actually, there will be odd exponents of $u$.

Comment: Oh! Whoops! Thank you for pointing it out, I notice the mistake. I guess my laziness got the better of me haha. This just turned the problem highly non-trivial (although, I would argue that the sixth degree polynomial is marginally more appealing than the square and cube roots)